# Slave to Slave Comminication with HC-06 devices?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is this possible, communication between HC-06 devices. A mean is this possible while i use 2 hc-06 devices send and receive data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a bluetooth connection at least one of the two devices must have the ability to start communication and to do so must be able to exercise the role of master. The HC-06 can only be a slave. Needs that at least one of the two was the HC -05, which can be configured as master and slave.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if i use phone and hc06 and than can i send to data/string hc06 side to my app ?

Comment: yes, you can use applications like this  [Serial bluetooth terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal) to communicate with the hc-06. Once connected you can also send from the hc-06 if it is connected to an arduino, for example, with the appropriate sketch.

Comment: if i use esp32 can i pair to hc06 ? How can i pair with them ?

Comment: I don't have this board ,you must search in datasheet if the bluetooth can be configured as master.